# Как вставить строку из TXT документа в HTML документ?

Tags: php, html, css, html5, txt

Допустим есть тег `<p class="text"></p>`, как вставить сюда текст из файла text.txt?

Comment: `$content = file_get_contents('text.txt');`  `<p class="text"><?= $content ?></p>`

Comment: @ArchDemon Это нужно вставлять прямо в HTML документ?

Comment: А я не знаю как у вас организован вывод текста на страницу